# Google Maps API V2 Blank Map

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to make a WebView application with Google Maps, but when I run it, it just shows a blank map.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public WebView mWB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWB = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWB);
        mWB.setWebViewClient(new MCWC());
        WebSettings webSET = mWB.getSettings();
        webSET.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWB.loadUrl("http://www.tomshardware.com/");
        Button btnEins = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntmap);
        btnEins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intencion = new Intent(v.getContext(),maps.class );
                startActivity(intencion);
            }

        });
    }
    public class MCWC extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean ShouldOverrideLoading(String url,WebView view){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mWB.canGoBack()) {
                        mWB.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

            /**@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
            }

             @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
             // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
             // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
             // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
             int id = item.getItemId();

             //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
             if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
             return true;
             }

             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
             }**/
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is maps.java

```
public class maps extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    UiSettings mapSettings;
    private final LatLng GEVGELIA = new LatLng(41.1421756,22.5026124);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps);
        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        CameraUpdate update  = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(GEVGELIA,15);
        map.animateCamera(update);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(41.139560, 22.503117))
                .title("Korzo"))
                .isVisible();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(41.142284, 22.504579))
                .title("SOU Josif Josifofski"))
                .isVisible();

    }
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            mapSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mapSettings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
            mapSettings.setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            mapSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gvglive.gvglive" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.gvglive.gvglive.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.barcodelibrary.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
                       Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".maps"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBEzDPkkL7c1VW9HS9KC8awuRsv9UpuA0M"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mWB">
    </WebView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bntmap"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="MAP"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/top"
        android:background="@drawable/top"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Added this to the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

I already checked my SHA1 fingerprint and the API Key,
I even tried regenerating a new API Key,
I have to mention that when I run it from android studio to my device it shows the map, but when I generate an apk and install it, no map is shown, I've also tried both app-release and app-debug.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ushMB.png

Comment: check `Google Console` if your `devices md5` is added there, otherwise you have to create a `signed apk` in order to show `Google Map`

Comment: As far as I know MD5 is a code just like the SHA1, and I did create a signed apk to install it on my phone and also my friends phone, if it matters my phone is Lenovo A880 and his is LG L70.

Comment: then check if you have enabled `google maps v2` on Google Console?

Comment: First of all get your devices `SHA1` code. Go to `Google Console->APIs&AUTH->Credentials` and on `Key for Android applications->Android Applications` add your `devices SHA1` key and `Regenerate API`. Check if it works

Comment: Already tried that, twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the Maps services by using the Google Play Services library from the SDK importing and referring it to through the project properties. OR if you are using Android Studio, Just create your project with default Maps project.

Please see the following working code... You can copy and paste the files as it is:

```
AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.avalunjkar.mymaps" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MapsActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

activitmaps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Please change the package name and add your API V2 key in Strings.xml or Manifest.xml.

Comment: Both the devices have google play services and also I should mention I followed google's tutorial for google maps.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Please see the edited Answer, I have just now tested this code and made it work.

Comment: It doesn't work, same gray screen when I launch from signed apk, but I am wondering why is it working when I run it from Android Studio